# How do I make a while loop of 2 conditons and stop at true condition

Tags: while-loop, sh

I want to create a while loop that request the user input for yes or no, if the user enter anything else it will loop until the user enters either yes or no

```
echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
read response
while [ "$response" != "yes" ] | [ "$response != "no" ] 
do
   echo "Please enter yes or no only"
   echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
   read response 
done
```

when i tried entering yes it still continues to loop but when i enter no it exits the loop

Answer (score 1):

In shell, the `|` (or **pipe**) operator is used to filter the output of the command on the left using the command on the right.

For example, the following line of shell:

`seq 1 3 | tac`

...will result in the lines produced by the command on the left...

```
1
2
3
```

...to be filtered by the command on the left (which will emit the lines in reverse order).  The output will be:

```
3
2
1
```

You're after an operator that performs a boolean operation on the exit statuses of two commands.  Since you're looking to continue the loop as long as the response is neither `yes` or `no`, the conjunction operator (`&&`) is what you're after:

```
echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
read response
while [ "$response" != "yes" ] && [ "$response" != "no" ] 
do
   echo "Please enter yes or no only"
   echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
   read response 
done
```

If the `bash` shell will always be available wherever you're running your script, this could be improved further by using `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`.  Besides a potential performance benefit, another advantage of using `[[` is that the requirements on strict quoting are relaxed:

```
echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
read response
while [[ $response != yes ]] && [[ $response != no ]] 
do
   echo "Please enter yes or no only"
   echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
   read response 
done
```

A further improvement comes from the knowledge that `[[` supports `&&` to conjoin two boolean expressions:

```
echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
read response
while [[ $response != yes && $response != no ]] 
do
   echo "Please enter yes or no only"
   echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
   read response 
done
```

Comment: `[` provides `-a` in place of `&&`

Comment: @jhnc Not entirely portably though.

Answer (score 0):

Just `while true` the whole thing until satisfied:

```
while true
do
    echo "Do you wish to save these settings?"
    read response
    if [[ "$response" = "yes" ]] || [[ "$response" = "no" ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    echo "Please enter yes or no only"
done
```